# ROS size of a message Vector

Tags: c++, ros

Hello i got a problem with getting the size of a ROS::Message which is vector

I have got the NaviManeuverSequence.msg:

```
Header header
uint8 carid
NaviManeuver[] maneuvers
```

and in maneuvers I sometimes have 3 vectors but sometimes also more. So I wanted to get the size of this vector by

```
NaviManeuverSequence.maneuvers.size();
```

but with this code I am just getting a 0 even though i can see in the debugger of Qt Creator that there are 3 Vectors in it.

Screenshot of debugger:

[screenshot of debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZTVK.png)

Thanks for your help mates

Edit:
I have forgotten to say that NaviManeuver[] contains a maneuvers message which contains uints, floats and more Vectors

Edit2 Working Example of my Subscriber:

```
Class Maneuver {
        Maneuver() {
             naviManeuverSubscriber = navi_node.subscribe("/mad/maneuver_sequence", 100, &ManeuverManagement::naviCallback, this);
        }
        void step() {
             uint32_t variable = naviManeuverSequence.maneuvers.size();
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal working example of your subscriber?

Comment: @Tik0 i hope i have done it like you thought? =)

Comment: I hardly believe that this is a working example. Please post a minimal working node by means of [Writing the Subscriber Node](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.Writing_the_Subscriber_Node)

Comment: You mean your missing my callback Function?  
    void naviCallback(const madmsgs::NaviManeuverSequence& rxmsg)
    {
        variabel = rxmsg
    }

Comment: The node is running without any problems I can use all variables from the node. But I just don't know how i can get the length of the vector which contains messages

Comment: I just assume that you have a scoping issue which is hard to say if you do not post the full code.

Comment: Please add the callback method to the minimal example of your second edit to get a working sample.